# SplitView for ipad and menu drawer for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, drawer

Im developing one Universal app (for iPhone and iPad both).
Following is the requirement of app .

**Requirement**

1.There should be a menu (master on the left) and detail (on the right).

2.For iPhone menu or masterViewController should be on drawer or on slide out menu.
[image: Drawer or slid out menu]

3.For iPad menu should be on rootViewController of splitView.
[image: menu in master of splitViewController]

**i have already tried**

I tried to implement it using `spiltViewController`, for iPad it is working fine (`MasterViewController` is coming on left of the screen and `DetailViewController` is on right side of the screen  ) but for iPhone it is simply working as `UINavigationController` (`MasterViewController` controller as `rootViewController` of `UINavigationController`).

**what approach should i use to implement it?**

Comment: That's normal as the iPhone is a much smaller screen space. If you want to do this you should consider creating a custom slide out navigation. Ray Wenderlich has a few tutorials, this is the latest http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Comment: @SASmith that i know but the problem is on iPad masterViewController should be placed on left side of the the screen like splitView not on slide out navigation or drawer.for iPhone it is fine .

Comment: Your question is not really clear about that my friend. You should consider putting that in there. Are you referring to when it is in Portrait mode? Add a little more detail to your question about this and I will try to help.

Comment: And it's not currently displaying with both the master and detail on iPad in Landscape?

Comment: For iPad it is working fine because i have implemented it using UISplitViewController but for iPhone i want this masterViewController to be placed in slide out menu and i don't want to create two different controller one for iPhone and one for iPad.

Comment: So you're asking - **How do I have the same menu on both iPhone and iPads using UISplitView on iPad and a drawer on iPhone?** Your question does not really define what you want. Also, is your menu static or will it be altered based on user input? If it is static then you set the menu content manually in storyboard, so there is no additional work coding. You just drag and drop labels in the cells. If it is dynamic, make a custom cell and reference it both the iPhone class and the iPad class.

Comment: Yes correct,I want to have same menu on both,Using UISplitView on iPad and using drawer on iPhone

Comment: @walinaqvi did you get this type of drawer? then please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS8 you can use [UISplitViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/) for this purpose.

The solution starts at 14:00 aprox in this WWDC 2014 video:
[View Controller Advancements in iOS8](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=214)

More info at:
http://coding.tabasoft.it/ios/the-new-uisplitviewcontroller/